# Navigation controllers and the rootViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I'm building a basic single view iBeacon app with a table displaying beacons and their properties. When it is just a single view application, everything works properly.

But when I embed this single view in a navigation controller, I receive the below error:

```
2014-10-15 16:47:09.633 beacon-iphone[14524:4714482] -[UINavigationController setBeacons:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d890f0
2014-10-15 16:47:09.634 beacon-iphone[14524:4714482] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setBeacons:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d890f0'
```

Which I believe is due to these lines of code in my `AppDelegate.m`, as the original table view is no longer the `rootViewController` when it is embedded in Navigation Controller.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    ViewController *viewController = (ViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    viewController.beacons = beacons;
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];

    // Do stuff if beacons are found
}
```

How would I refactor this to account for the navigation controller? I apologize if this is a trivial question, as I am still an iOS rookie

Below is my storyboard with the working code. As mentioned, it only breaks when I embed this in a Navigation Controller

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root view controller is now the navigation controller, so you need to access its topViewController property to get ViewController,

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    ViewController *viewController =  (ViewController *)nav.topViewController;
    viewController.beacons = beacons;
    [viewController.tableView reloadData];

    // Do stuff if beacons are found
}
```

Comment: This is generating a warning of: `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'ViewController *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'` in the `ViewController *viewController = nav.topViewController` line

Comment: @Anconia, sorry, that's because I left off a cast in that line. I've updated my answer

Comment: Funny, I just type casted it and was about to respond - thanks for the quick response! Will type casting the view have any reprimands?

Comment: @Anconia, no, it's what you should do. It doesn't really do anything other than silencing the compiler warning.